# Deshabilitar boton atras en android

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente problema, inicio una `Activity` para crear un usuario, donde esta me muestra un `View dialogLayout` al principio donde se ingresa un parámetro del usuario para validar q el mismo no exista ya, el tema esta en que si yo presiono el botón atrás, se me cierra el `View dialogLayout` y me queda abierto el formulario de registro. Ya probé utilizando un `onBackPressed` pero me cierra solo el `View dialogLayout`, y yo necesito q se cierre todo el `View dialogLayout` y la `Activity`

```
public class CrearCuenta extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout crearCuenta;
    Context context;
    Dialog dialog;
    EditText nombre, apellido, dni, fechaNac, direccion, telefono, email;
    Spinner obraSocial, grupoSanguineo;
    ImageView fechaNacDP;
    String [] items;
    int dia, mes, anio, posicion, documento;
    Usuario u;
    Persona p;
    Paciente pa;
    long idOS, id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crear_cuenta);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        context = CrearCuenta.this;
        crearCuenta = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.registrarUsuario);
        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaNombre);
        apellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaApellido);
        dni = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaDni);
        fechaNac = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaFechaNac);
        fechaNacDP = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cuentaCalFechaNac);
        direccion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaDireccion);
        telefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaTelefono);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuentaEmail);
        obraSocial = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cuentaSpinnerOS);
        grupoSanguineo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cuentaSpinnerGS);
        pedirDni();
        final ControladorObraSocial controladorOS = new ControladorObraSocial(context);
        controladorOS.cargarSpinnerOS();



        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, controladorOS.listaOS);
        obraSocial.setAdapter(adaptador);
        obraSocial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayList<ObraSocial> lista;
                lista = controladorOS.listaOS();
                posicion = position;
                if (position > 0) {
                    idOS = (lista.get(posicion - 1).getIdOS());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.grupos);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        grupoSanguineo.setAdapter(ad);
        grupoSanguineo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });


        fechaNacDP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                dia=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                mes=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                anio=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        fechaNac.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
                    }
                }, dia,mes,anio);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });



        crearCuenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (validarCampos() == true) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_cargar_pass, null);
                    final EditText pass = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.edtPass);
                    final EditText repass = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.edtRePass);
                    Button cancelar = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelarCrearUsuario);
                    Button aceptar = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnCrearUsuario);
                    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                       ControladorUsuario ctrlUsuario = new ControladorUsuario(context);
                        ControladorPaciente ctrlPaciente = new ControladorPaciente(context);
                        ControladorPersona ctrlPersona = new ControladorPersona(context);
                        id = (ctrlUsuario.getUltimoId()+1);

                        String psw = pass.getText().toString();
                        String rpsw = repass.getText().toString();
                        if (psw.equals(rpsw)) {
                            setUsuario(psw, id);
                            setPersona(id);
                            setPaciente(id);

                            try {
                                ctrlUsuario.agregarUsuario(u);
                                ctrlPersona.agregarPersona(p);
                                ctrlPaciente.agregarPaciente(pa);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            confirmacion();
                          limpiarcampos();

                        }else {
                            errorPass();
                        }
                    }
                });


                cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setView(dialogLayout);
                dialog = builder.show();

                }
                else {
                    errorCampoIncompleto();
                }


            }
        });


    }


    public void limpiarcampos(){
        nombre.setText("");
        apellido.setText("");
        dni.setText("");
        direccion.setText("");
        telefono.setText("");
        email.setText("");
    }

    public void confirmacion(){
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlgAlert.setMessage("Se ha agregado exitosamente!");
        dlgAlert.setTitle("Agregar Persona");
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent agregar = new Intent(context, Pantalla.class);
                        startActivity(agregar);
                    }
                });
        dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
        dlgAlert.create().show();
    }

    public boolean validarCampos(){
        if (nombre.getText().toString().length() > 0 && apellido.getText().toString().length() > 0 && dni.getText().toString().length() > 0 && direccion.getText().toString().length() > 0 && telefono.getText().toString().length() > 0 && email.getText().toString().length() > 0 ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Usuario setUsuario(String pass, long id) {
        u = new Usuario();
        u.setUsuario(dni.getText().toString());
        u.setPass(pass);
        u.setEstado("Pendiente");
        u.setIdUsuario(id);
        return u;
    }


    public Persona setPersona(long id){
        p = new Persona();
        p.setIdPersona(id);
        p.setNombre(nombre.getText().toString());
        p.setApellido(apellido.getText().toString());
        p.setDni(dni.getText().toString());
        p.setFechaNacimiento(fechaNac.getText().toString());
        p.setDireccion(direccion.getText().toString());
        p.setTelefono(telefono.getText().toString());
        p.setEmail(email.getText().toString());

       return p;
    }

    public Paciente setPaciente(long id){
        pa = new Paciente();
        pa.setIdPaciente(id);
        pa.setIdOS(idOS);
        pa.setGrupoSanguineo(grupoSanguineo.getSelectedItem().toString());
       return pa;
    }

public void pedirDni(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pedir_dni, null);
    final EditText dniTxt = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.pedirDni);
    Button aceptar = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.aceptarPedirDni);
    Button cancelar = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancelarPedirDni);



    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ControladorPaciente ctrlPaciente = new ControladorPaciente(context);
            documento = Integer.parseInt(dniTxt.getText().toString());
            boolean existePaciente = ctrlPaciente.validarPaciente(documento);

            if (existePaciente == true){
                Toast.makeText(context, "El DNI ya se encuentra registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
                dni.setText(dniTxt.getText().toString());
                dni.setEnabled(false);
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
    }});

    cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(dialogLayout);
    dialog = builder.show();

}



    public void errorCampoIncompleto(){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error, campos sin completar!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void errorPass(){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error!!!, las contraseñas no coinciden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Agrega el código que trataste, no entiendo muy bien lo que comentas, recuerda que onBackpressed cierra la Activity no dialogos.

Comment: ahi te agregue el codigo, necesito que cuando le doy atras se cierre todo Dialog y Activity o q no haga nada cuando le doy atras sin cerrar Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes 2 opciones ya que estas utilizando  `AlertDialog.Builder`, una es deshabilitar el boton físico de back de esta manera:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setCancelable(false);`

esto hace que tu dialog no se pueda cerrar ya sea con el botón de back, o pulsando fuera de tu dialog.

y de esta manera tu puedes cerrar la actividad y el dialogo al momento que se da click al botón de cancelar.

la otra opción es agregar un listener a tu dialogo para saber cuando se cierrar.

`builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                this.finish() // el this es el context de tu actividad.
            }
        });`

de esta manera aunque el usuario presione el botón de back tu puedes cerrar el dialogo y tu activada al mismo tiempo.

espero mi respuesta te sea de utilidad saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, problema solucionado!